# getting error :Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting error in this line in below code available in try block

```
error : Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

 "   columnsArray.push({ field: item.columnname, title: (columnHeaderArray != null && columnHeaderArray.columnHeaders[index]), cell: (item.columntype === "DateTime" ? customDateTimeCell : item.columnname?.toUpperCase() === ("Status").toUpperCase() ? CostumStatus : undefined), show: true, minWidth: 100, filter: getfilterType(item.columntype) })
            });"
```

---

```
try {
                
            debugger

            columnsData.forEach((item, index) => {

                columnsArray.push({ field: item.columnname, title: (columnHeaderArray != null && columnHeaderArray.columnHeaders[index]), cell: (item.columntype === "DateTime" ? customDateTimeCell : item.columnname?.toUpperCase() === ("Status").toUpperCase() ? CostumStatus : undefined), show: true, minWidth: 100, filter: getfilterType(item.columntype) })
            });
            columns.cols = columnsArray;
        } catch (error:any) {
                console.log(error.message)
        }
```

some one please help me to resolve above error

Comment: Could you put the full code to make a better analysis? But I believe that the `columnHeaderArray` value can't read